# Modify elements of a nested list in base R without loops

Tags: r, lapply, nested-lists

I have a nested list with two or more elements at the top level and want to modify named elements of the sub-lists, e.g. by appending values from a named vector.

Let's assume `L` is a list of two elements and `N`is a vector with the same number of elements:

```r
L <- list(
  foo = list(
    x1=1,
    x2=c(a=1, b=2)
  ),
  bar = list(
    x1=2,
    x2=c(e=2, f=3)
  )
)

N <- c(n=11, n=12)
```

Then I want to get a result like this:

```r
list(
  foo = list(
    x1=1,
    x2=c(a=1, b=2, n=11)
  ),
  bar = list(
    x1=2,
    x2=c(e=2, f=3, n=12)
  )
)
```

It is easy to read the elements of the sub-lists:

```r
lapply(L, "[[", "x2")
```

So I wonder if there is a similarly compact way to change elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `Map` to loop over the `L`, and corresponding elements of `N`, extract the 'x2' component and append the `N` values and assign back, return the object (`x`)

```
L2 <- Map(\(x, y) 
          {
          x$x2 <- c(x$x2, n=y)
          x
          }, L, N)
```

-checking with OP's output

```
> all.equal(L2, out)
[1] TRUE
```

---

Or a variant is to assign with the name

```
Map(\(x, y) {x$x2['n'] <- y; x}, L, N)
```